# How to extract rectangles - contours dilation

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to extract rectangles from an image. I couldn't fit rectangles on the boxes. I tried to use multiple methods of contours also contour dilation, kernel size and etc. But none of those worked for me.

```py
    file = os.path.join(fol, os.listdir(fol)[l])
    im = cv2.imread(file)
    
    
    kernel_size = 1
    iterations = 2
    thickness = 2
    
    # result = RemoveLines(im, threshold=1200)
    result = im.copy()
    im = result.copy()
    Original = im.copy()
    # contours1, letter, tables, im = get_contours(im, kernel_size=5)
    
    im1 = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    Filter = True
    ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(im1,189,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    kernel = np.ones((kernel_size, kernel_size),np.uint8)
    dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh1,kernel,iterations = iterations)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
      
    
    tables = []
    contours1 = []
    # Extracting the Outer Bound boxes
    #contours = [(cnt,hie)[0] for cnt,hie in zip(contours,hierarchy[0]) if hie[2] != -1]
    # Extracting the Boxes with more than 8% area
    for cnt,hie in zip(contours,hierarchy[0]):
        #x,y,w,h = cnt[0],cnt[1],cnt[2],cnt[3]
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        if cv2.contourArea(cnt)>1200:
          #bound the images
          cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),thickness)
          #im = cv2.putText(im, str(count), (x,y-5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, (0,0,255), 1)
          contours1.append(cnt)
          letter = Original[y:y+h,x:x+w]
          tables.append(letter)
```

[image]

Would some one please help me or show me the direction to extract all the rectangles image boxes from an image?

My region of interest is right down corner box. So I want to extract data from it.